# Does linux (kernel) support Intel speed shift?

Tags: kernel, drivers, cpu, intel

Windows 10 support Intel speed shift.

Does Linux (kernel) also support it?

Speed shift related info:

https://www.anandtech.com/show/9751/examining-intel-skylake-speed-shift-more-responsive-processors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should support since 3.19:

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.19/source/drivers/cpufreq/intel_pstate.c

```
static void intel_pstate_hwp_enable(void)
{
    hwp_active++;
    pr_info("intel_pstate HWP enabled\n");

    wrmsrl( MSR_PM_ENABLE, 0x1);
}
```

another commit (v3.19-rc1):

intel_pstate: Add support for HWP

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/2f86dc4cddcb21290ca099e1dce2a53533c86e0b#diff-d06e88b1dd6d576c23e3654d87258879

Answer (score 5):

Intel speed shift aka HWP (hardware-managed P-states) is working for Intel Kaby Lake since kernel 4.10:

- [cpufreq: intel_pstate: Disable energy efficiency optimization](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=6e978b22efa1db9f6e71b24440b5f1d93e968ee3) *git.kernel.org kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git*
- [Kaby Lake is unleashed with Linux kernel 4.10](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3173618/kaby-lake-is-unleashed-with-kernel-410.html) *PCWorld*
- [KernelNewbies: Linux_4.10](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.10#ACPI.2C_EFI.2C_cpufreq.2C_thermal.2C_Power_Management)
- [intel_pstate CPU Performance Scaling Driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/admin-guide/pm/intel_pstate.html) *The Linux Kernel
  4.12.0 - The Linux kernel user’s and administrator’s guide*
- [x86_energy_perf_policy (8)](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch-backports/linux-cpupower/x86_energy_perf_policy.8.en.html) *MANPAGES stretch-backports / linux-cpupower*

Comment: In Windows with ThrottleStop, you set a Speed Shift value to adjust performance vs usage. Do we get to adjust that value in Linux or how does it handle it?